# Record changes in a different table

Tags: json, postgresql, triggers, jsonb

I have successfully set up a history table according to this tutorial:
https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/

My problem is that this function saves both the whole new record and the whole old record as jsons.

How can I alter this function so that only those column titles and values will be added to the json, which have really been changed?
In other words how can I replace the expression 'row_to_json(OLD)' with one which represents only the difference between row_to_json(NEW)  row_to_json(OLD)?

```
CREATE FUNCTION change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$

BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
        THEN
            INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val)
                VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW));
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF   TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
        THEN
            INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val)
                VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP,
                    row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF   TG_OP = 'DELETE'
        THEN
            INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_val)
                VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD));
            RETURN OLD;
    END IF;
 END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

Comment: http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/

Comment: Thank you unfortunately the subtraction gives an error:                                                                       
Error synchronizing data with database

Reason:
SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb - jsonb
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function change_trigger() line 13 at SQL statement

Comment: This is why you cannot just copy code and expect it to work. The error you are getting is completely *resolved* in the description where the author states: "I couldn’t really see how to replicate the update part so simply without creating a delete operator. Once that operator has been created it appears to work". You need the same. Follow the link for [delete operator](https://github.com/glynastill/pg_jsonb_delete_op). It creates the necessary missing operator.

Comment: Did you read the sentence in the first paragraph? "*but I counldn’t really see how to replicate the update part so simply without creating a delete operator. Once that operator has been created it appears to work*" - https://github.com/glynastill/pg_jsonb_delete_op

Comment: I found this article and it helped: https://coussej.github.io/2016/05/24/A-Minus-Operator-For-PostgreSQLs-JSONB/

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out that

- I needed to convert the 'NEW' and 'OLD' rows to jsonb. (to_jsonb(NEW))
- I needed another function which does the subtraction
  https://coussej.github.io/2016/05/24/A-Minus-Operator-For-PostgreSQLs-JSONB/